# UIButton in Today widget not calling connected IBAction and not showing image

Tags: ios, widget

I added simple button to Today widget view controller.
As you can see on Interface Builder screenshot below button image is visible and there is action connected to button 'click'.
But when I display widget on device neither image is visible nor action is called in view controller.

[image: Interface Builder screenshot]

Here is widget screenshot

[image]

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of the widget in today section of your device

Comment: Can you show us the constraints please?

Comment: @Kerberos the constraints of a button are: leading, top and width = superview leading, top and width, and button aspect is 1:1

Comment: @MarekJ. Sorry but I don't think I understood, anyway you have a warning in the constraints. Check it and try to solve the warning.

Comment: @Kerberos I fixed constraint warning and updated XCode screenshot to show constraints, but nothing changed

Comment: Mine is working fine . here's the screenshot. Redefine your constraints also make sure image file has a reference with Your widget target.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85coG.jpg

Comment: Select your image at the left side it will show Target membership,make sure your Target name is checked.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtxX8.png

Comment: @Friend thx, adding target helped! image now shows and 'click' action is called. Strange that XCode does not report in any way that image is not in proper target ...
Will you post it as an answer? So anyone could vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes your widget target is not referencing the image that you are showing in widget Storyboard. Select your image at the left side it will show Target membership,make sure your Target name is checked. i.stack.imgur.com/wtxX8.png